# How to validate the select tag with javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, select

I'm building an animated form, so far i'm only able to validate the input tag and make it work with my form animation, but i need to use the select tag as well in the form, and i not able to make it work with the animation, please help me with some advise.
thanks!

https://codepen.io/andrewrico/pen/gyEGaw

```
function animatedForm() {

  const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-arrow-down");

  arrows.forEach(arrow => {
    arrow.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const input = arrow.previousElementSibling;
      const parent = arrow.parentElement;
      const nextForm = parent.nextElementSibling;

      if (input.type === "text" && validateUser(input)) {
        nextSlide(parent, nextForm);

      } else if (input.type === "email" && validateEmail(input)) {
        nextSlide(parent, nextForm);

      } else if (input.type === "password" && validateUser(input)) {
        nextSlide(parent, nextForm);

      } else {
        parent.style.animation = "shake 0.5s ease";
      }

      parent.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
        parent.style.animation = "";

      });
    });
  });
}

function validateUser(user) {
  if (user.value.length < 6) {
    console.log("not enough characters");
    error("rgb(189, 87, 87)");
    return false;
  } else {
    error("rgb(101, 109, 255)");
    return true;
  }
}

function validateEmail(email) {
  const validation = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
  if (validation.test(email.value)) {
    error("rgb(101, 109, 255)");
    return true;
  } else {
    error("rgb(189, 87, 87)");
    return false;
  }
}

function nextSlide(parent, nextForm) {
  parent.classList.add('inactive');
  parent.classList.remove('active');
  nextForm.classList.add('active');
}

function error(color) {
  document.body.style.background = color;
}

animatedForm();
```

the select tag should be able to pass the validation in order to pass to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code seems to be input oriented, you just go in the else in *animatedForm()* ,you will have to create a special case for you select to test selected value.

Comment: can you give an idea how to get around it? Thanks!